# Though YouTube has completely changed it's UI, why I am still stuck with the old icon for the subtitles button?

Tags: youtube, user-interface, subtitles

Though YouTube has updated it's layout and in the new layout the media control buttons like the subtitles button has a different icon now but I am still stuck with old icon. Everything is working fine the whole UI of YouTube has changed for me but I am still stuck with the old icon, I don't know why this is happening!

[image: New and Old versions]

Comment: It's probably just caching. Clear your browser history and it'll probably resolve itself.

Comment: @ale I have tried this quite a few times and each time nothing changes this happens in all the Browsers chrome,safari,firefox,opera,yandex and what not and I would also like to mention that I tried these https://thenextweb.com/google/2016/05/02/youtube-getting-googles-material-design-heres-enable-now/#.tnw_Gtm4QzEy steps a long ago when YouTube was experimenting Material Design!